# Ask for retry upon a failure of the network API call by using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am using ReactiveCocoa in my iOS app for the network API requests. What if I want to show an UIAlertView and ask for user to click on the retry button and a retry on the same API call only happens when user click on the retry button, how is that supposed to do?

```
- (RACSignal*) fetchImportantData {
    return [RACSignal createSignal: ^RACDisposable*(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        return [apiCall subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            [subscriber sendNext:x]; 
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
RACSignal * catchSignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Try again"
                               message:@""
                               delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertView.rac_buttonClickedSignal subscribeNext:^(NSNumber * buttonIndex) {
        if (buttonIndex.integerValue != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
        {
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }
        else
        {
            [subscriber sendError:nil];
        }
    }];
    [alertView show];
    return nil;
}];

[[[[[self fetchImportantData] catchTo:catchSignal] repeat] take:1] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"NEXT: %@", x);
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
} completed:^{
    NSLog(@"COMPLETED");
}];
```

So what's happening here is the error from `fetchImportantData` is being caught by `catchTo:`, and the signal is then replaced by whatever is sent by that signal (it's kinda like `flattenMap:`, but for errors). Since we now have control, we can wire up `sendCompleted` to the "Yes" button and use `repeat` to have the signal repeat upon completion, while wiring up `sendError:` to the "No" button so that we can have all subscription stop immediately if the user doesn't want to retry.

When `fetchImportantData` finally returns a non-error, it'll be sent through and completely skip our `catchTo:` block, and the signal will complete thanks to our `take:1`.